# Access to audio part of the video file

Tags: matlab, audio, video, multimedia, matlab-guide

I have wrote the following MATLAB code but all the AudioFrame are zero ?!? 
Could anyone help me please ?

```
[filename pathname]=uigetfile({'*.*'},'Video Selector');
fulpathname=strcat(pathname,filename);
hmfr=video.MultimediaFileReader(fulpathname,'AudioOutputPort',true,'VideoOutputPort',false);
[VideoFrame,AudioFrame] = step(hmfr);
```

Is the problem related to video file or my MATLAB code ?

How can I access to my audio file ?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
hmfr=video.MultimediaFileReader(filename,'AudioOutputPort',true,'VideoOutputPort',false);

while ~isDone(hmfr)
  audioFrame = step(hmfr);
end
close(hmfr);
```

Comment: It just gives me a zero array.

Comment: @amir: Whats your video file format? I've tried it with MP4. would you update your question and put the your code exactly?

Comment: I have also test with MP4. Error using MultimediaFileReader/setup
Could not create the converter to process the data

Error in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\matlab\system\+matlab\+system\+mixin\FiniteSource.p>FiniteSource.isDone (line 39)

Comment: It seems the error is line 39, I can not help you if you do not show me the code!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First I select filename then I just copy your code and past it to MATLAB command prompt. It gives me : Error using MultimediaFileReader/setup
Could not create the converter to process the data

Error in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\matlab\system\+matlab\+system\+mixin\FiniteSource.p>FiniteSource.isDone (line 39)

Comment: please copy all of contains of your .m file and paste here.

Comment: >> audioFrame

audioFrame =

     -8     -3
     -9     -5
     -8     -4
     -6     -4
     -5     -5
     -7     -3
     -9      0
     -7      0
     -7     -3
     -9     -4
     -8     -2
     -5     -1
     -5     -2
     -5     -2
     -1     -1
      0      0
     -1     -1
      0     -1
      0      0
     -6      0
     -7     -1
      0      0
      2      0
     -2     -2
     -4     -2
     -2      0
     -1      1
     -2      0
     -1     -1
     -4     -2

Comment: it just gives me meaningless results. Please look at the above ?!?

Comment: @amir: I need all of your code include in Line 39 to help you!

Comment: Dear @mohammad there is no line 39 in my code. I just copy and past the code to my matlab prompt.